# Is it possible to return a list of async items in an async method from an async source?

Tags: c#, async-await

Essentially I'm trying to be able to do this:

```
var thingTasks = thingFactory.GetMyThings();
// ...
var things = await thingTasks;
```

I'm trying to start from a list of objects, iterate through that list making an `async` call for each one, and returning the set of results in an `await`-able way so the consumer can choose when to `await` it. `GetMyThings` itself uses `await` before generating the list, so it needs to be `async` itself and is something like:

```
public async Task<List<Thing>> GetMyThings() {
    var thingMakers = await GetThingMakers();
    var things = thingMakers.Select(async thing => await thing.GetAsync());
    return things;
}
```

The basic idea is that I have some `await` lines, then after that I use the results of those lines to generate a list and generating each item also requires an `async` call. I'm trying to avoid blocking within the method (e.g. `.Result`) and instead pass that responsibility/opportunity back to the caller. Basically, start the tasks in the list but not `await` them. This naturally makes me want to return `Task<List<Thing>>` or 'List>`.

The closest I got was `return Task.WhenAll(things)` but that didn't work (it needed to be `Task<Task<Thing[]>>` and `await await GetMyThings()`. Alternatively, `return Select(...)` returning a `Task<List<Task<Thing>>>` and needing a `await Task.WhenAll(await GetMyThings())` on the consuming side.

In both cases one needs double `await` statements to realize the list. I'm thinking it's impossible but is there a way to avoid the double `await`?

Comment: `async thing => await thing.GetAsync()` is just `thing => thing.GetAsync()` which is also the same as `GetAsync`.  No need to unnecessarily wrap it.

Comment: If you don't want to have the caller need to unwrap the results, then have the method itself unwrap the results before returning them.  The method can unwrap the results in exactly the same way that you had the caller doing it.

Answer (score 1):

Use `Task.WhenAll` to await all task at once. This way you will run each `GetAsync` approximately at the same time. So :

1. Start all task
2. Await all
3. Return task's results

Like this :

```
public async Task<List<Thing>> GetMyThings()
{
    var thingMakers = await GetThingMakers();
    var tasks = thingMakers.Select(thing => thing.GetAsync());
    var things = await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
    return things.ToList();
}
```

Answer (score -2):

If you want to make the inner tasks await-able outside, you need to actually return them:

```
public async Task<List<Task<Thing>>> GetMyThings() {
    var thingMakers = await GetThingMakers();
    var things = thingMakers.Select(thing => thing.GetAsync());
    return things.ToList();
}
```

You can then use this call like this:

```
List<Task<Thing>> thingTasks = await GetMyThings();
await Task.WhenAll(thingTasks);
List<Thing> = thingTasks.Select(t => t.Result).ToList();
```

Or even:

```
List<Thing> things = await GetMyThings()
    .ContinueWith(async r => 
        {
            await Task.WhenAll(r);
            return r.Select(r => r.Result).ToList();
        });
```